# Does MySQL InnoDB always require an index for each foreign key constraint?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, innodb

I am using phpMyAdmin. In order to set up a foreign key constraint with InnoDB (under the "Relation View" link on the Structure tab) it appears that I need to add an index for the field to which I want to add the restraint. This obviously has an impact on performance of inserts/updates on the table, particularly if there are several constraints I want to add. Is it possible to specify a foreign key constraint or relational integrity in InnoDB without the need to create an Index for the required field?

Many thanks
JS, London

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [MySQL reference manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html):

> InnoDB requires indexes on foreign
>   keys and referenced keys so that
>   foreign key checks can be fast and not
>   require a table scan. In the
>   referencing table, there must be an
>   index where the foreign key columns
>   are listed as the first columns in the
>   same order. Such an index is created
>   on the referencing table automatically
>   if it does not exist. (This is in
>   contrast to some older versions, in
>   which indexes had to be created
>   explicitly or the creation of foreign
>   key constraints would fail.)

Answer (score 1):

a foreign key contraint refers 1 key to another one. A foreign key is also an index.
So yes you need to index collumn (either with unique or with foreign key) to use them in a foreign key constraint.

There's 3 types of indexes available:
- primary key
- unique index
- non-unique index