# Is it ok to have cyclic foreign key dependencies in a relational database?

Tags: database-design, foreign-keys, directed-acyclic-graphs

I'm writing a code to backup a MySQL database into a binary file. I'm aware of `mysqldump` but for some reasons I can't use trivial methods. What I'm currently doing:

1. read schema definition
2. sort tables by foreign key dependencies
3. select rows in all tables (100 rows each time) and write them in a binary file

Definition of Dependency: A table `T1` depends on existence of table `T2` if and only if at least there is one foreign key in `T1` pointing to `T2`'s key.

A numeric value is assigned to each table. This value specifies order of tables. For tables with no dependency, this value is `0` for others it's maximum value of tables that current table depends on them; plus one. If there is a `-1` in the set of values of depended tables, value of current table remains undefined (`-1`). Initially value of all tables is `-1` which means unspecified.

This is C++ code:

```
// tablesQueue: Queue of all tables
// orderedQueue: Resulting order

while(! tablesQueue.isEmpty())
{
    bool satisfied = true;
    foreach(TableNode* parent, tablesQueue.head()->referencedTables)
    {
        if(parent->degreeOfFreedom == -1)
        {
            satisfied = false;
            break;
        }
        else
           // handle error blah blah ... 
    }
    if(satisfied)
    {
        int max =0;
        foreach(TableNode* parent, tablesQueue.head()->referencedTables)
        max = (max < parent->degreeOfFreedom+1) ? 
                  parent->degreeOfFreedom+1 : max;
        tablesQueue.head()->degreeOfFreedom = max;
        orderedQueue.enqueue(tablesQueue.dequeue());
    }
    else
    {
        tablesQueue.enqueue(tablesQueue.dequeue());
    }
}
```

If there is a cycle in dependency graph of tables, this algorithm does not terminate.

Normally is this OK to have such a design for tables? For example two tables having foreign key to each other. Surprisingly I found that example databases provided by Oracle for MySQL (`sakila`) have a lot of such cycles. I'm supposing that it's possible to remove all that cycles by adding a third table [?]

Comment: I don't see a problem with cyclic foreign key dependencies as long as there is at least one link in the cycle that is allowed to be null (i.e. _not_ declared `NOT NULL`).

Comment: @IanRoberts Problem occurs when you try to write all data into a file and restore it again. Suppose that you're reading data from you'r backup file for table `A` at row `n`. It's depended on existence of corresponding row in `B`; say row number `m`. You need to have wrote `m`th row of `B` before `n`th row of `A`. But in the case that `m-i`th row of `B` have a key pointing to `n+j`th key of `A` you have no valid order of tables to restore your database.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Circular dependencies are fairly common. Some examples:

- A table references itself when implementing the ["adjacency list"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14671930/533120) hierarchy.
- Two tables reference each other when implementing the 1:1<sup>*</sup> relationship.
- Two tables referencing each other is one of the possible implementations for the 1:N relationship (where one of the rows on the "N" side is "special").
- Furthermore, I've seen situations with multiple tables forming a "ring"...

So yes, it is "OK" to to have circular dependencies.

---

<sup>*</sup> Strictly, a *true* 1:1 requires deferred constraints to solve the chicken-and-egg problem (which are not supported in MySQL), otherwise you can only have 1:0..1 or 0..1:0..1. But in all these cases, you have two tables referencing each other.

Comment: In this situation, backup and restore wont work. I'm going to disable foreign key checks before restore and enable it again. (two queries with `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;` and `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;`)

Comment: EXEC sp_msforeachtable "ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT all"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159038/can-foreign-key-constraints-be-temporarily-disabled-using-t-sql

Comment: ...AND disabling checks doesn't work to gen scripts.