# MySQL Error: Error creating table: Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to set up a reference between two tables, and I keep running into this error when I load the page.

```
Error creating table: Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

This is the 'calendars' table:
[calendars table image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLaz7.png)

And this is the current query I am running to create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE `'.$classTableName.'`(
    classID INT(11) NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    users INT(11) NOT NULL,
    files INT(11) NOT NULL,
    chats INT(11) NOT NULL,
    deadlines INT(11) NOT NULL,
    calendar INT(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (classID), 
    FOREIGN KEY (calendar) REFERENCES calendars(classID)
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Any help would be appreciated! :)

Comment: Do you have an index on `calendars.classID`? The foreign key has to point to a column with an index. Usually it points to the primary key of the table.

Comment: Instead of the image, show the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE calendars`.

Comment: Adding a primary index on calendars.classID has solved it, thanks so much!

Comment: This should be closed as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1721841/does-mysql-innodb-always-require-an-index-for-each-foreign-key-constraint

Answer (score 0):

Had to index `calendars.classID`, as pointed out by Basmar.